# Latex algorithm. Can't get it to work

Tags: algorithm, latex

Im trying to write an algorithm using the `algorithm` package, but when I use any keyword (if, while, state, etc) it won't compile

Here's what I type in (snippet)

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculate $A_{nxn}$}
\label{Algorithm 1}

\IF{$n<0$}
\STATE $x \leftarrow X$
\ENDIF


\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

> *geometry auto-detecting driver*
>   *geometry detected driver: pdftex* (/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
>   [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version
>   2006.09.02).] ) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
>   [2] ! Undefined control sequence. l.94
>   \IF
>           {$n<0$} ? q

## update

These are all the packages i'm using.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

Any thoughts? I'm kind of lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look into utilizing http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Justin Thanks, I´ll get in there as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a peek here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms_and_Pseudocode

Are you missing a `\begin{algorithmic}` declaration, perhaps? From the examples, it appears that `\begin{algorithm}` is a container for the actual `algorithmic` environment where the work takes place...

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article} 
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{algorithm} 

\caption{Calculate $A_{nxn}$} 
\label{Algorithm 1} 

\begin{algorithmic}

\IF{$n<0$} 
\STATE $x \leftarrow X$ 
\ENDIF 

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

That wiki page also includes a link to the official algorithms manual.

Comment: Could you tell us exactly which package you are using (e.g., provide a URL)?  I would originally have given you an answer along the lines of @djacobson's answer, and I'm not sure which other algorithm-related package you are using.

Comment: Andrew, I'll list all of the packages im using in my question.

Comment: PDF link leads to a login page, would be nice to have a link that doesn't require you to sign up.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the suggestions here, but none of it worked for me. Here is the approach that worked for me: I deleted `\usepackage{algorithmicx}`, and loaded only `\usepackage{algorithm}` and `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`. As indicated in their documentation [here](https://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf). You don’t need to manually load the `algorithmicx package`, as this is done by`algpseudocode`.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\begin{document}  
   \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
            \State $a\gets b$
            \State $b\gets r$
            \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
        \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: See below:]